# Изменение структуры директорий в проекте Zend Framework

Tags: framework, php, zend-framework

Как как настроить проект ZF, чтобы вместо директории public использовалась, к примеру, public_html? Получаю ошибку:

> `Not Found The requested URL /controller/action was not found on this server.`

Comment: С включенной опцией AllowOverride All все отлично работает, но к httpd.conf нет доступа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено добавлением директивы "RewriteBase /".

.htaccess выглядит так:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```